# Java bitwise AND incorrect output?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Java gives incorrect output when using Bitwise AND:

```
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long a = -26000;
        System.out.printf("%X\n", a);
        // upper 32-bits are 0 (implicitly)
        System.out.printf("%X\n", (a & 0xFFFFFFFF));
        // upper 32-bits are 0 (explicitly specified)
        System.out.printf("%X\n", (a & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF));
    }
}
/*
Output:
FFFFFFFFFFFF9A70
FFFFFFFFFFFF9A70
FFFFFFFFFFFF9A70
*/
```

Code link: https://godbolt.org/z/Y8q3MhdK5

Any ideas why?

Comment: I'm guessing it's all to do with [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) which is the common way to store negative integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0xFFFFFFFF` and `0x00000000FFFFFFFF` are both `int` literals, representing the value -1.

When `&` is applied on a `long` and an `int`, the `int` undergoes [numeric promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6), and gets converted to a `long`.

> Otherwise, if any expression is of type long, then the promoted type is long, and other expressions that are not of type long undergo [widening primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) to `long`.

During this conversion, the value is sign-extended,

> A widening conversion of a signed integer value to an integral type T simply sign-extends the two's-complement representation of the integer value to fill the wider format.

so you still get the same value (-1) as a `long`. -1's bits are all 1, so you get the same result.

To get the intended result, add the `L` suffix to these literals, so they are actually `long`s, and does not get sign-extended.

Answer (score 3):

Your constants are ints. 0xFFFFFFFF and 0x00000000FFFFFFFF are both -1. These are equivalent to 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL. Use 0xFFFFFFFF**L** and 0x00000000FFFFFFFF**L** instead and you'll see the results you want.